# Systemd start script fails with exit code 127

Tags: debian, systemd

I'm trying to set up a Terraria server Debian but I'm stuck on getting it to work nicely with systemd. 
I've taken a systemd script from [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/game-servers/host-a-terraria-server-on-your-linode/#systemd) but when I try to start it, I only get this:

```
$ sudo systemctl start terraria
Job for terraria.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status terraria.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

$ sudo systemctl status terraria
● terraria.service - server daemon for terraria
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/terraria.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-10-25 20:23:27 CEST; 7s ago
  Process: 3606 ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -dmS terraria /bin/bash -c /home/terraria/server/TerrariaServer.bin.x86_64 -config /home/terraria/server/serverconfig.txt (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 3342 (code=exited, status=127)

Oct 25 20:23:27 systemd[1]: Starting server daemon for terraria...
Oct 25 20:23:27 systemd[1]: terraria.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=127
Oct 25 20:23:27 systemd[1]: Failed to start server daemon for terraria.
Oct 25 20:23:27 systemd[1]: terraria.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 25 20:23:27 systemd[1]: terraria.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Is there any way for me to find out what actually causes the exit code 127 (i.e. which part the system can't find)?

This is the complete systemd script:

```
[Unit]
Description=server daemon for terraria

[Service]
Type=forking
User=terraria
KillMode=none
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -dmS terraria /bin/bash -c "/home/terraria/server/TerrariaServer.bin.x86_64 -config /home/terraria/server/serverconfig.txt"
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/terrariad exit

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

All paths actually exist, when I try to execute the ExecStart line manually it works as it should (starts the Terraria Server inside a screen env).

Comment: Are you executing it as sudo when you do you manual test?  Type=forking may not be quite right here but I don't think that affects it exiting immediately...`journalctl -xe` help?

Comment: Both with and without sudo works. `journalctl -xe` only shows `terraria.service: Unit entered failed state.` and 
`terraria.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.`

Comment: when you are doing your manual test are you executing it as user terraria?  Also sometimes it may help to specify a group as well...

Comment: Already tried it with a group, didnt' change anything. And yes, even as user terraria, executing it manually works perfectly fine.

Comment: What if you set it to start "last" that help? https://superuser.com/a/573761/39364 This is like debugging via chat LOL

Comment: Just for good measure, please add to the question the lines from `journalctl` around Oct 25 20:23:27 (with a margin of a couple of seconds).

Comment: @rogerdpack
Doesn't change anything (except that systemd doesn't show the code 127 as failure).

Comment: @FerencWágner You can see the output here: https://gist.github.com/tobi1449/d64d93b4f2e84fc0654574aa956814e1
Doesn't seem as if there's anything helpful in it though

Comment: Nothing in the following lines either? Anyway, try extending your command line like `ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -dmS terraria -L -Logfile /tmp/terraria.log /bin/bash -c "/home/terraria/server/TerrariaServer.bin.x86_64 -config /home/terraria/server/serverconfig.txt"` and see what `/tmp/terraria.log` contains after a failed start attempt.

Comment: Maybe add a `2>/tmp/terraria.log 1>&2` to the bash -c "..." inside the quotes as well :)

Comment: I didn't think it would be useful, but in retrospect it might be: add an "after=network-online.target" though a handful of people have found even that isn't enough so you have to add a restart https://github.com/google/cloud-print-connector/issues/140 (or add a "sleep 10" into the bash side of things LOL). GL!

Comment: @FerencWágner Nope, after those lines in the gist comes the pam message that the sudo session has closed.

Comment: @rogerdpack both your and FerencWágner's suggestions didn't do anything unfortunately, neither of them even resulted in a logfile to begin with. I'm starting to suspect there's either something wrong with screen or with systemd itself since I've noticed that the startscript for my minecraft server (also using screen) stopped working with the same error aswell.

Comment: you could put it into a bash file so you could redirect the stderr more easily.  It's hard to know at this point exactly what you've tried and haven't, but oh well, post back if you figure it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it was a Systemd bug. Forcing a systemd update via `apt install systemd` resolved it.

Comment: Nice. What version did it update to?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the user.

I've noticed an error when I tried to call

```
terrariad exit
```

on terminal, it asks for password when comes in

```
su - terraria -c "$cmd"(line 13)
```

So I changed the user in "terraria.service" and "terrariad", and it works. Is not the ideal to run the service on main user but for me is only for fun.

I'm still trying to figure out how to solve the problem running the service on terraria user. But for now I'm running "as is".